# Freshman year forces problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces

I have been sitting with this problem for about 2 hours now. I know it involves simultaneous equations of some sort... I am trying to figure out maybe if there was not enough information given .. maybe the community could help me out :)

[Question:*It Is Question 2*](http://puu.sh/7Y6yG.jpg)
[image: Image of question 2]

[My Approach](http://puu.sh/7Y6Bu.jpg)
[image]

Comment: It's hard to see the image you posted, but it looks like you are on the right track.    Make sure that you have counted all the forces, and then make sure that when you consider the $x$ and $y$ components separately that you have a contribution for *each* force, for *both* directions.

Answer (score 1):

There is enough information.
Think about the tension in the rope on either side of the pulley - it's the same.  Then look at the vertical forces.